# QtCreator: Stopped at internal breakpoint

Tags: qt, gdb, qt-creator, archlinux

I'm using Qt Creator (QtCreator2.6.1 & Qt4.8.4 64bit) on Arch Linux, and I have a problem while debugging. If I run a debug build, whether I have set any breakpoints or not, Creator (or GDB, I suppose) keeps stopping at standard Qt functions and saying **Stopped at internal breakpoint 2 in thread 1.**. It's always the same message.

How can I stop breaking on "internal breakpoints"?

I've gotten this problem on several Qt functions, but the only one I recall specifically is "addWidget". In my current project, I have a QMainWindow that has as its central widget a QGLWidget. I can add a widget to the main window by calling "layout()->addWidget( m_DlgCur );" from the main window. However, it always breaks on that line. In some of my larger projects, it breaks on other functions too!

For completeness, I have included the entire code for the main window:

```
qrpgWND::qrpgWND( QWidget *Parent )
:   QMainWindow( Parent )
,   m_CntWgt( QGLFormat(QGL::SampleBuffers|QGL::DoubleBuffer|QGL::AlphaChannel|QGL::HasOverlay), this, 0 )
,   m_Layout( NULL ), m_DlgCur( NULL )
{
    m_Layout = new QHBoxLayout();
    m_CntWgt.setLayout( m_Layout );
    setCentralWidget( &m_CntWgt );
    m_BtnCls.setText( "Exit" );
    Q_ASSERT(
        connect(    &m_BtnCls,  SIGNAL(clicked(bool)),
                    this,           SLOT(btnCls())  )
    );
    Q_ASSERT(
        connect(    &m_BtnCraft,    SIGNAL(clicked(bool)),
                    this,               SLOT(btnCraft())    )
    );
    m_Layout->addWidget( &m_BtnCls );
    m_BtnCraft.setText( "Craft" );
    m_Layout->addWidget( &m_BtnCraft );
return;
}

void qrpgWND::btnCraft()
{
    if( m_DlgCur == NULL )  {
        m_DlgCur = new qrpgDlgCrafting( &m_DlgCur, &m_CntWgt );
        layout()->addWidget( m_DlgCur );
        m_DlgCur->show();
    }
return;
}
```

Comment: Do you have a file .gdbinit? See http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/43833-GDB-Cannot-Remove-Internal-Breakpoint